# Adding an always visible suffix to a paragraph truncated to two lines

Tags: html, css

Consider the following example.

```css
p {
  width: 300px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
```

Let's say that there is a string e.g. `Hello there` that must always be visible *at the end* of the truncated text.

For example, instead of:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
printing and typesetting industry. Lorem...
```

The rendered output would be:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
printing and typesetting... Hello there
```

The catch is that the element (in this example, `Hello there`) has an unknown length (but guaranteed to not be greater than 1/3 of the line length).

Is there CSS solution that would do this?

Comment: Maybe `position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0`?